# Windows mobile 6.1 vpn service using Witopia connects and immediately disconnects

Tags: vpn, pptp, windows-mobile-6

My samsung Omnia i900 with Windows mobile 6.1.  vpn service using Witopia pptp connects and immediately disconnects.  Witopia tech sent me the log so I know its connecting, but as soon as I try to open my browser and go to (for example) skype it shows it as blocked.  The VPN works fine on my PC over the same router. I am in the UAE where they block many sites.  I have tried to log on to the witopia server using both the ip address and the server name with the same results.